# Python - WHILE loop nested in FOR loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I was trying to achieve this output:

```
0;12
1;24
2;36
3;48
4;60
```

... but I got this:

```
0;12
1;12
2;12
3;12
4;12
```

Here is the code:

```
iter = 0
count = 0
letter = 0
for iter in range(5):
    while letter < len("hello, world"):
        letter+=1
        count+=1
    print("Iteration " + str(iter) + "; count is: " + str(count))
```

I managed to fix this by adding `count*(iter+1)` instead of `count` in print statement, but what I'm trying to understand is why *count* variable resets every time when new *for* iteration begins. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the rules for constructing the numbers after `;`? It's always `i += 12`?

Comment: After the first `while` completes, letter is equal to the length of hello world, so `count` is never incremented in the second and subsequent interations. So (where) should you (re)initialise `letter`?

Comment: looks like your code and expected output doesn't match

Comment: Initialising `iter` is unnecessary. for-lops do the variable stuff for you.

Comment: @mrblewog You are right, I should initialize(reset) *letter* after every completed while iteration. Between *for* and *while* statement ```letter = 0```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`letter` is always 13 since it is not reinitialized. So while loop will be executed only once. To fix this,

```
count = 0
for iter in range(5):
    letter = 0
    while letter < len("hello, world"):
        letter+=1
        count+=1
    print("Iteration " + str(iter) + "; count is: " + str(count))
```

Comment: `iter = 0` is also unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is you never set `letter` to 0 after an interation. So `letter` always stays at 12.

Printing letter like this:

```
iter = 0
count = 0
letter = 0
for iter in range(5):
    while letter < 12:
        letter+=1
        count+=1
        print(letter)
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

After the first while iteration `letter` stays at 12 and therefore `while letter < 12:` is never run so `count` never increases.

Make sure to set `letter` to 0 after each `while` loop:

```
iter = 0
count = 0
letter = 0
for iter in range(5):
    while letter < 12:
        letter+=1
        count+=1
    letter=0
```

Answer (score 0):

there! this can be fixed by resetting letter to 0 after each while loop. The while loop will only run the first time because, during the second time, the letter value increases to 13 and is no longer < len("hello, world").

```
iter = 0
count = 0
letter = 0
for iter in range(5):
    while letter < len("hello, world"):
        letter+=1
        count+=1
    print("Iteration " + str(iter) + "; count is: " + str(count))
    letter=0
```